# How to control multiply consoles from Java code?

Tags: java, async, tcp

I have Java application. I try to realize *multiplayer* chat with
    **TCP**
protocol, but I have an issue.
I cannot output all messages I get on client tier *(server tier works perfectly)*, because I give an input to user and create a thread to read messages from **TCP** client, so

```
<Scanner object>.nextLine();
```

Is blocking an output of my app. I can create by ***Swing***, but I still haven't fully understood it.

I have two options:

1. Output all new messages from queue after sending message by user.
2. Somehow detach input and output.

I think you don't need to explain that in 1st option if user will go out for a long time, he will need to send a message before he will get all these new messages.

Only the second option remains. I need to **detach** input and output and I found that in some *"interactive tasks"* there are two consoles - first used for *input*, other - for *output*. But can I do it into a Java? And if I can, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Swing, you can make the traditional two-control "chat" layout:

`┌────────────┐
│output      │
│output      │
│output      │
│...         │
└────────────┘
┌────────────┐
│input> _    │
└────────────┘`

Send one thread to output to the top area, another thread to *listen to changes* in the bottom area. You can send bottom area's contents to the top area, too, if you want an unified log. You will need line-level buffering, though, like traditional terminals have; they hae it for a reason. Without it, *parts* of lines would intermix.

If you want Linux / macOS / other posix console, use some wrapper around `curses` to reproduce the layout like above, and don't read `stdin` directly.

(If you need Windows console, I have no idea what to use.)

Comment: I wrote into my question that _I can create by Swing, but I still haven't fully understood it._ I tried, but I cannot make app's structure.

Comment: I suppose you should take a tutorial, [like this](https://ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html), read more on [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), and generally do more googling. This topic is _very_ popular, there are tons of example Java TCP + Swing chat example code.

Comment: OK, but __TCP__ client not the only reason to detach _input_ & _output_. There are many tasks that need detaching, and I hope I won't make a _Swing_ app for each one personally, and in this question I tried to know: how can I control at least 2 consoles at the same time.

Comment: This depends on what are these consoles. For posix pseudoterminal interface (aka `pty`) it seems possible but neither usual nor particularly easy. A process can theoretically open more than one pty device. It would likely be easier to just run a local telnet server with different "consoles" on different ports / unix sockets, and let a `telnet` client handle the pty stuff. For Windows consoles, I have no idea. It would be great to understand [which problem are you _really_ solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).